# Ways to optimize hive query

Tags: hive

I have the following hive query

```
DROP TABLE dwo_analysis.spark_custom_global_authenticated_experiment_dashboard_report_activity;
CREATE TABLE dwo_analysis.spark_custom_global_authenticated_experiment_dashboard_report_activity (
    experiment_name varchar(255),
    variant_name varchar(255),
    first_date string,
    guid string,
    click_date date,
    create int,
    publish int,
    sumCreate int,
    sumPublish int
)
PARTITIONED BY (click_date date)
STORED AS ORC tblproperties("compress.mode"="SNAPPY");




INSERT INTO TABLE dwo_analysis.spark_custom_global_authenticated_experiment_dashboard_report_activity
SELECT
    'EmailDripCampaignGlobal' as experiment_name,
    'treatment' as variant_name,

    MIN(TO_DATE(b.min_date)) as first_date,
    SUBSTR(post_evar12,1,24) AS guid,
    click_date,

    MAX(CASE WHEN post_prop5='project:createClicked' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS create,
    MAX(CASE WHEN post_prop5='project:exportCompleted' OR post_prop5='project:reExportCompleted' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS publish,

    SUM(CASE WHEN post_prop5='project:createClicked' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS sumCreate,
    SUM(CASE WHEN post_prop5='project:exportCompleted' OR post_prop5='project:reExportCompleted' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS sumPublish

    FROM sourcedata.sc_visitor_click_history_jun_2015 sc

    INNER JOIN dwo_analysis.spark_experiment_email_drip_treatment b
    ON SUBSTR(sc.post_evar12,1,24) = b.guid

    WHERE report_suite='adbemmarvelweb.prod'
    AND sc.date_time >= b.min_date
    AND click_date >= '2018-01-01'
    AND click_date < DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, 3)

    GROUP BY SUBSTR(post_evar12,1,24), click_date;
```

It takes a long time to execute. Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can optimize? Reason why it takes a long time is because the sc_visitor_click_history_jun_2015 table is 10T heavy

Answer (score 0):

Enable hive vectorization and try.

**set hive.vectorized.execution.enabled = true;**